# How to convert UWP StorageFile to .NET FileInfo?

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-standard

Now that UWP supports .NET Standard 2.0, it has access to more of the System.IO namespace, including [Fileinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

How does one convert an UWP [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) to a Fileinfo? And a StorageFolder to a DirectoryInfo for that matter?

The naïve approach (get the StorageItem's full path and construct a Fileinfo using it) fails when trying to open the resulting Fileinfo, and I'd really like to get away from using [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) if possible.

Comment: your naive implementation works good in uwp on windows 10 desktop, i can access the resulting fileinfo, for example show message with it's  Directory.FullName. Maybe it is dependent on Provider, under windows 10 name is "This PC" (LOL)

Comment: That works fine until you try opening that FileInfo to get a stream.

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.File and System.IO.FileInfo have long been available to UWP apps. They aren't new with .Net Standard 2.0

StorageFile and FileInfo don't do the same thing and aren't generally interchangeable. You don't say what error you're getting, but my guess is that it is AccessDenied because your app doesn't have direct access to the path you are trying to use.

By default apps have direct file access only to their ApplicationData and InstalledLocations. They can use System.IO to access those locations directly. To access other locations that have been granted access by the user (directly through a File picker, implicitly by package capabilities, etc.) the app needs to go through the file broker via the StorageFile and StorageFolder classes.

You can get a brokered Win32 file HANDLE from [IStorageHandleAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt765063(v=vs.85).aspx) and initialize a System.IO.File from it, but FileInfo doesn't provide a way to construct from a HANDLE.

Comment: I am getting the StorageFile in question via a file picker, I am aware of the limitations due to UWP sandboxing. The issue is getting a stream out of those FileInfos: while I can open the StorageFile I get just fine, constructing a FileInfo using its path and trying to open it causes an exception (access denied).

Comment: The FileInfo doesn't get brokered access. You can use it only for locations the app can directly write. For others you need to stream from the StorageFile or use IStorageHandleAccess to initialize a System.IO.File.