# How to use UWP's StorageFolder in a .NET Standard library (which expects DirectoryInfo)

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard

Related information:

- [How to convert UWP StorageFile to .NET FileInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017495/how-to-convert-uwp-storagefile-to-net-fileinfo)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021840/10540210

In the context of a UWP application, even when the user has granted permission to use a given folder through the [FolderPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), subsequent access to the folder *must* still happen through the Windows.Storage API's.

What is the best practice for going from a *StorageFolder* in the 'UWP API scope' to a library written in a '.NET Standard API scope' which internally uses *DirectoryInfo*.

**UPDATE**

I've already included the 'broadFileSystemAccess' capability to the Package.appxmanifest:

```
... xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation>/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
... IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"
... <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

Comment: You may get appropriate answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814889/how-to-access-a-file-in-net-standard-2-0-dll

Comment: That question, and the related answer linking to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49854399/10540210 mentions the broad file system capability as a possible answer. I've already added this capability with no real results. I can use DirectoryInfo with a path directing to a known UWP folder (or sub folder). I'll update my question with the appxmanifest information.